# Implementation Dependency Excluded from Runtime Configuration

Tags: gradle

When adding dependencies as implementation in my gradle file, they are not being included when listed as part of the runtime configuration. For example, they are excluded when attempting to put them into a pathing jar as follows:

```
task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    appendix = 'pathing'

    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
```

However, when moving these back as a compile dependency, this works. The issue with this is now at compile time my classpath is much larger. My understanding is implementation should be treated as compile time in the direct consumer and runtime transitively, so why are they excluded from that configuration? This also does not work when specifying them as "api". This is using gradle 5.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runtime` configuration is deprecated and is replaced by `runtimeOnly`. This old configuration doesn't know about the newer `implementation` or `api` configuration, so this is why you don't see your dependencies when resolving it.

What you want is of cause not to resolve the `runtimeOnly` configuration, but rather resolve the classpath used at runtime. This configuration is called `runtimeClasspath`. Example:

```
tasks.register("patchingJar", Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    appendix = 'patching'

    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect {
                it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
```